# Движение вектора на плоскости

Tags: python, matplotlib, линейная-алгебра

Столкнулся со следующей задачей, очень нужна помощь, уже который день ищу проблему.

Мой скрипт на Python подключается к визуалке, где мне нужно перемещать объект, пока просто на плоскости. Очевидно, что для этого я использую AB вектор. К сожалению, в линейной алгебре не силён, но вроде как нужные формулы нашёл.

Представим себе следующую простую задачу в цикле:

1. Двигаем вектор вперёд на 0.1 (движение у объекта постоянное)
2. Нормализуем вектор, т.к. он увеличился после движения.
3. Поворачиваем его (вектор) на 1 градус.

Т.е. получаем такое вот круговое движение. На данный момент имею следующие 3 функции под движение, нормализацию и поворот:

```py
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, pow, radians
 
def forward(v: list, distance: float = 0.1) -> list:
    vector_direction = [v[1][0] - v[0][0], v[1][1] - v[0][1]]
    cos_dir = vector_direction[0] / sqrt(pow(vector_direction[0], 2) + pow(vector_direction[1], 2))
    sin_dir = vector_direction[1] / sqrt(pow(vector_direction[1], 2) + pow(vector_direction[1], 2))
    new_x, new_y = (distance * cos_dir) + v[1][0], (distance * sin_dir) + v[1][1]
 
    return [v[0], [new_x, new_y]]
 
 
def normalization(v: list) -> list:
    len_vec = sqrt((v[1][0] - v[0][0]) ** 2 + (v[1][1] - v[0][1]) ** 2)
    kv = (len_vec - 1) / len_vec
    return [[v[0][0] + (v[1][0] - v[0][0]) * kv, v[0][1] + (v[1][1] - v[0][1]) * kv], v[1]]
 
 
def turn(v: list, direction: bool) -> list:
    ONE_GRAD = -radians(1) if direction else radians(1)
 
    new_x = -sin(ONE_GRAD) * (v[1][1] - v[0][1]) + cos(ONE_GRAD) * (v[1][0] - v[0][0]) + v[0][0]
    new_y = cos(ONE_GRAD) * (v[1][1] - v[0][1]) + sin(ONE_GRAD) * (v[1][0] - v[0][0]) + v[0][1]
 
    return [v[0], [new_x, new_y]]
```

Далее пробую всё это дело тестировать, например вот так:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from vector_displacement import normalization, forward, turn
 
START = 0
 
vector = [[START, START], [15, 15]]
 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 40), ylim=(0, 40))
 
 
def draw_vectors(vector_a: list):
    # plt.plot([vector_a[0][0], vector_a[1][0]], [vector_a[0][1], vector_a[1][1]])
    ax.plot(vector_a[1][0], vector_a[1][1], "go", markersize=1)
 
 
for number in range(360):
    draw_vectors(vector)  # Отрисовка вектора на графике
    vector = forward(vector)  # Двигаем вперёд
    draw_vectors(vector)  # Отрисовка вектора на графике
    vector = normalization(vector)  # Нормализовали
    vector = turn(vector, False)  # Повернули
 
 
plt.savefig('./dir/graph{}.png'.format("result5"))
```

Т.е. должно получиться круговое движение. А получается по этому коду вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В другую сторону и с векторами разных знаков получается примерно то же самое. Т.е. в какой то момент он перестаёт поворачиваться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Экспериментов за это время была масса, и со специалистом по линейной алгебре я тоже консультировался, но его расчёты на первый цикл полностью совпали с моими. Думаю, может где-то глупая ошибка затесалась, которую не вижу. В районе 30 градусов он поворачивать не хочет. По сути наблюдаю в логах постоянное уменьшение угла поворота, вплоть до мизерных значений, что приводит к остановке.

Поворот без движения и нормализации - работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Движение с поворотом без нормализации - тоже работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нормализовать и поворачивать, но без движения - аналогично всё работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за любую помощь и подсказку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сдаётся мне, что вы путаете векторы положения и скорости, иначе бы не делали с одним и тем же "Двигаем вектор" и "Поворачиваем его (вектор)"

Задайте позицию - я буду писать без индексов, чтобы не путаться - с компонентами `px, py` и скорость `vx, vy`.

На каждом элементарном шаге (после единичного интервала времени) позиция меняется

```
px += vx
py += vy
```

Если интервал времени может меняться, то домножайте на него скорость

Если нужно изменить направление движение на угол `Fi` без изменения абсолютного значения скорости:

```
t = vx
vx = vx * cos(Fi) - vy * sin(Fi)
vy = t * sin(Fi) + vy * cos(Fi)
```

Если нужно задать абсолютное направление под углом `Theta` со скоростью V:

```
vx = V * cos(Theta)
vy = V * sin(Theta)
```

Если нужно изменить модуль скорости без изменения направления в K раз:

```
vx *= K 
vy *= K
```

Нормализованный вектор направления

```
V_Mag = sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy)
u_vx = vx / V_Mag   (== cos(направления))
u_vy = vy / V_Mag   (== sin(направления))
```

Если нужно задать скорость V без изменения направления:

```
V_Mag = sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy)
vx *= V/V_Mag
vy *= V/V_Mag
```

Движение вперед на расстояние Dist

```
px += u_vx * Dist
py += u_vy * Dist
```

Проверочка:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, pow, radians, pi


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 25), ylim=(0, 25))

def draw_vectors(px, py):
    # plt.plot([vector_a[0][0], vector_a[1][0]], [vector_a[0][1], vector_a[1][1]])
    ax.plot(px, py, "go", markersize=1)

px = 15
py = 15
vx = 15
vy = 15

V_Mag = sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy)
u_vx = vx / V_Mag
u_vy = vy / V_Mag

for number in range(360):
    draw_vectors(px, py)  # Отрисовка вектора на графике
    px += u_vx * 0.1
    py += u_vy * 0.1
    draw_vectors(px, py)  # Отрисовка вектора на графике
    t = u_vx
    u_vx = u_vx * cos(pi/180) - u_vy * sin(pi/180)
    u_vy = t * sin(pi/180) + u_vy * cos(pi/180)

plt.savefig('e:/graph{}.png'.format("result5"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за столь подробный ответ, особенно за пример с кодом. Понял, что не правильно подходил к этой задаче и представлял себе иначе решение. Проблему благодаря вам решил. Как будет время, буду подтягивать линейную алгебру :)